# Как задать свойство background-image элементу li?

Tags: css

Хочу поставить к элементам `li` `background-image`. Прописываю все верно, но в отладчике браузера это свойство перечеркивается и картинка не выводится, 
хотя перед этим я уже так делал в коде другого блока, и там выводится нормально, а здесь вот так.

```
#rightTop ul li {    
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../images/img7.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 136px;
    height: 91px;
}
```

Comment: Покажите код ..

Comment: #rightTop ul li {
    
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../images/img7.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 136px;
    height: 91px;
}
вот так прописываю

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @pavlofff ага, посмотрел на правки. Меня тут больше огорчает описание правки, чем ее содержание.

Answer (score 4):

Уберите кавычки "

```
#rightTop ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../images/img7.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 136px;
    height: 91px;
}
```

Comment: ппц вот что значит не внимательность

Answer (score 0):

можете ещё и через `list-style-image`: добавить фоновые изображения